# "Ignoreheading" Beamer Environment doesn't work with :BEAMER_act: Overlay

Tags: org-mode, org-export, beamer

What I would like to do is the following:

I have a beamer frame where I added `:BEAMER_act: [<+->]`.
This works well with all blocks that follow, but not when I set `:BEAMER_env: ignoreheading`.

Example:

```
#+OPTIONS: ':nil *:t -:t ::t <:t H:2 \n:nil ^:t arch:headline
#+LATEX_CLASS: beamer
* Greetings and saying goodbye
** What are greetings?
   :PROPERTIES:
   :BEAMER_act: [<+->]
   :END:
*** Greeting
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_env: definition
    :END:
A *greeting* is something you say to greet someone.
*** 
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_env: example
    :END:
- ``Hello world''
- ``What's up?''
*** 
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_env: ignoreheading
    :END:
We will discuss ways to say goodbye on the next slide.
```

(Note that I have set `#+OPTIONS: H:2`)

What works is that each block and each bullet point comes one-by-one.
The only problem is the last sentence in the ignoreheading "block" (it actually isn't a block, and I guess that's where the problem is...), which appears on every slide of the "What are greetings?" frame.

An ugly solution I found is to enclose the last sentence in beamer code as such: `@@beamer:\onslide<+->{We will discuss ways to say goodbye on the next slide.}@@`.

Surely there must be a more practical (and prettier!) solution to this.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Hm I found one solution: I can add the line `#+BEAMER: \pause[\thebeamerpauses]` above the three starred headline.  Not sure if this is best...

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `\pause` either before the ignored `***` heading,  or before the `We will discuss...` text. I've found that manually inserting `\pause` is more reliable than `Beamer_act`

Comment: yes that is what i have done now (see my comment).  well i guess i might often be better to do presentations direclty in with latex instead of in org mode...